# Java3d viewPlateform vs viewingPlatform

Tags: java-3d

I'm having trouble understanding what the difference is between the viewplateform and the viewingPLatform. Could someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the documentation?

quote:

The ViewPlatform leaf node object controls the position, orientation and scale of the viewer. It is the node in the scene graph that a View object connects to. A viewer navigates through the virtual universe by changing the transform in the scene graph hierarchy above the ViewPlatform.

ViewingPlatform is used to set up the "view" side of a Java 3D scene graph. The ViewingPlatform object contains a MultiTransformGroup node to allow for a series of transforms to be linked together. To this structure the ViewPlatform is added as well as any geometry to associate with this view platform.

/quote

Does that explain it will enough?  You may need to do some wider reading to put some of this in context.  The scene graph the Java3D employs abstracts us away from the nitty gritty of dealing with the tricky aspect of 3D graphics; we just have to learn how to deal with it from the higher level. Effectively, it's a tree into which all the graphical aspects are put, and it splits into two main forks; one for content, and one for controlling how you see that content. 
These are both view fork objects.  The 'ViewingPlatform' is a management node that bring other aspects together, where as the 'ViewPlatform' is a leaf node that controls specific aspects, as detailed above.